# Hide checkbox in java with Scenebuilder

Tags: scenebuilder, eclipse-jee

I am working with eclipse jee photon and scenebuilder.

What I am trying to do: 
I have a choicebox with two labels:
ObservableList  labelList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("examlpe01", "example02");

If example01 is chosen, the checkbox should be visible but disabled. If example02 is chosed the checkbox should be visible and it should be possible to check it.

---

Here is my code:

```
public class newUser{

    ObservableList <String> labelList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("example01", "example02");

    @FXML
    private TextField name;

    @FXML
    private TextField lastName;

    @FXML
    private Button saveUser;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox adminRights;

    @FXML
    private TextField emailAdress;

    @FXML
    private TextField password;

    @FXML
    private Button userSpeichern;

    @FXML
    private MenuButton userDropDown;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem adminpage;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem example01;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem example02;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem logout;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox label;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
    label.setItems(labelList);
    label.setValue("mm");
    }

    @FXML
    void logout(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    Parent Login = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("fxml/Login.fxml"));
    Scene Login_scene = new Scene(Login);
    Stage app_stage = (Stage) userDropDown.getScene().getWindow();
    app_stage.setScene(Login_scene);
    app_stage.show();

    }

    DbHelper db = new DbHelper();

    private void showCheckbox() {
    if (label.equals("example02")) {

        }
    }

     @FXML
     void saveUserData(ActionEvent event) {   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
@FXML
ChoiceBox choiceBox;

@FXML
CheckBox checkBox;

@FXML
private void choiceBoxOnClicked() {
    if (choiceBox.getValue().equals("example01")) {
        checkBox.setDisable(true);
    } else if (choiceBox.getValue().equals("example02")) {
        checkBox.setDisable(false);
    }
}
```

So this should work.